# Write permission for a specific folder in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, file-permissions

My question is preaty simple. Is there any way to give current user (IIS User, in this case, ASP NET USER) permission to write to a specific folder location (folder inside our web application) using web.config? Because, it's getting boring to ask to the web hoster to gain access to a specific folder each time we want to do a file uploader on a website.

I know it's maybe preaty simple to find an answer using google, but it keeps returning me how to write INTO web.config instead of permission to write into web.config FOR a specific folder. In addition, I'm french so my english is not at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If that was possible, you could write an application which, when deployed on a server, would allow you to write to any directory on the disk despite write access being denied by the administrator.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question. But if he needs acces to a folder on his own website, that's not uncommon. He should have ftp access already to his own website. I believe maybe I don't understand who is trying to write where.

Comment: His FTP account definitely has write access at least to the application folder, but he is asking how to grant another user (specifically, the ASP NET USER) some filesystem-level rights. If i understand the question correctly, the actual question is: "can user X grant himself write access to a specific directory?" (he wants to do this via web.config, which is processed by IIS using the ASP NET USER account - so ASP NET USER would be granting the write access to itself).

Comment: Well thanks. Thats exactly what I want to know. I'll try something else then.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily grant permissions for a local user (e.g. the user that the IIS worker process/app pool is running as) to a folder anywhere on your filesystem actually through rights permissions in Windows itself but this does not allow for doing this through the web.config file itself. Please give us a description of what you're trying to do specifically and there may be a better solution. The solution I mentioned above could be a bit of a security risk but it depends on the needs and situation.

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I understand .NET (and web.config) don't really control write permissions.

You'll need to either expose the folder from a filesystem and/or webserver level to allow people access (though this may be somewhat of a security issue depending on your scenario). Or another possibility would be to create a simple web-page that allows uploading files to the directory.

Comment: I guess the problem IS the making of that simple web-page that allows upload...

I have the same issue, if not web.config can an installer do the permission trick?